How to properly setup a standalone NTP server?
Machines:

Virtual Machine with Ubuntu Mate acting as NTP server (192.1.1.125)
Embedded linux with ntpd service to act as NTP Client

What I did (Server Side):

sudo apt-get install ntp
sudo nano /etc/ntp.conf
removed all server and pools
added "server 127.127.1.0" and "fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10"
Save the file and restart ntp service

What I did (Client Side):

Enabled NTP (ntpq and ntpd) on buildroot and compile
killall ntpd
edit /etc/ntp.conf, remove servers and add "server 192.1.1.125 iburst"
run "ntpd" to start the service
Time synchronize (sometimes it get stuck to .INIT. )

Couple of questions:

Is this the correct way to setup a standalone ntp server?
On the server I want to change the time and check how the NTP client acts, but when I run the following commands "sudo timedatectl set-ntp no" and "sudo timedatectl set-time " the time keeps resetting to the original one although the ntp is disabled (service still running obviously) any idea on why of this?
When running ntpq -pn I sometimes get "No association ID found" kind of error, what is the cause of this?

Config file server side:
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

# Leap seconds definition provided by tzdata
leapfile /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list

# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

# Specify one or more NTP servers.

# Use servers from the NTP Pool Project. Approved by Ubuntu Technical Board
# on 2011-02-08 (LP: #104525). See http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html for
# more information.

#server 192.1.1.125
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10
# Use Ubuntu's ntp server as a fallback.
#pool ntp.ubuntu.com

# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for
# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>
# might also be helpful.
#
# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration
# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end
# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Needed for adding pool entries
restrict source notrap nomodify noquery

# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if
# cryptographically authenticated.
#restrict 192.168.123.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrust


# If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.
# (Again, the address is an example only.)
#broadcast 192.168.123.255

# If you want to listen to time broadcasts on your local subnet, de-comment the
# next lines.  Please do this only if you trust everybody on the network!
#disable auth
#broadcastclient

#Changes recquired to use pps synchonisation as explained in documentation:
#http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-config-adv.htm#AEN3918

#server 127.127.8.1 mode 135 prefer    # Meinberg GPS167 with PPS
#fudge 127.127.8.1 time1 0.0042        # relative to PPS for my hardware

#server 127.127.22.1                   # ATOM(PPS)
#fudge 127.127.22.1 flag3 1            # enable PPS API


Client Configuration:
server 192.1.1.125 iburst
#server 1.pool.ntp.org iburst

# Allow only time queries, at a limited rate, sending KoD when in excess.
# Allow all local queries (IPv4, IPv6)
restrict default nomodify nopeer noquery limited kod
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict [::1]


You haven't specified the version of Ubuntu you are using, but in newer versions the use of chronyd is recommended: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/how-to-serve-the-network-time-protocol-with-chrony

@FedKad Forced to use NTPD

A number of points here:

ntpd doesn't work well in a VM, especially as a server, because the vm starts and stops and pauses irreguarly and disrupts its time keeping.   It can't keep accurate time this way.  But, then, I get the impression you don't care about accurate time, you just want to play with ntpd, so maybe this is ok.
ntpd wasn't designed to run standalone, it has to have external references, the more the better.  The local RTC is not a good reference.  It needs either other ntp servers or a GPS. It will refuse to serve the time if it doesn't have good references, hence the message  "No association ID found".
Use timedatectl to configure where the system gets its time, not if ntpd is running.  Use systemctl start ntp and systemctl stop ntp to do that.
ntp won't serve a fake time, it wants a gps or atomic clock somewhere in its references, even if it's indirect.  If you want to serve fake time, you'll have to create a fake physical time reference.
ntp can't do large time corrections.  It expects to start with the clocks synchronized within a second or two and then it might take hours to sync.  Use ntpdate (which uses sntp) to initially set the time close enough for ntpd to synchronize.
It will get stuck in INIT if it can't get accurate external time sources.  Again, it doesn't work stand alone.

ntp isn't designed to set your clock (although it can), it is designed to stabilize it over a long period of time.  It will actually crash if your clock drifts too far for it to correct.
